# How do I guard a pop?

Tags: arrays, typescript, strict

I'm using strict mode. I've got the following code:

```
const a: string[] = [];
// something that fills `a`
while (a.length > 0) {
  const i: string = a.pop();  // Error on this line
  console.log(i); 
  // maybe add something else to `a`
}
```

In this case, I'm getting an error on the line, because `pop` has a return type of `string | null`. Which makes sense for a general use of the `pop` method, but I'm guarding against that case? Is there a more typescript way of doing this to get the proper typeguard?

I can't just loop over the array (e.g. using `of`), because sometimes `a` gets new items added to it during the loop and the semantics aren't the same.

Comment: How about using the [non-null assertion operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html#non-null-assertion-operator): `const i = a.pop()!;`?

Comment: "but I'm guarding against that case?" – Yes you are, but TypeScript doesn't know that. Figuring out whether or not some code path may or may not lead to `null` is equivalent to solving the Halting Problem, and thus impossible. You can only do it for simple things like `const topOfStack = a.pop(); if (topOfStack !== null) { /* TypeScript knows topOfStack is non-null */ }`.

Comment: @CRice That's a decent workaround for not being able to guard it, but that's not the question. The `!` is not a guard, it's an assertion. I'm looking for a guard (I think that's the right term)

Comment: @JörgWMittag I can understand that detecting all cases is impossible. I'm wondering if there are any cases where typescript does support a guarded pop. i.e. where pop has guards that have been built in. apparently checking the length isn't sufficient. Is there anything else that could work? You've proposed a post operation guard for the resultant type, which is close, but doesn't work as cleanly for the case I have.

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you check pop data before you pop?

```
if (a[a.length -1]) {
    const i: string = a.pop()
}
a.pop()
```

Comment: Doesn't work. `a.pop()` is still `string | undefined`

Comment: That's almost exactly the same as what I have.